# HTML page with link (picture) to another HTML page with video that doesn't play properly

Tags: html, video

I am having trouble with an HTML file that consists of only a video. When I play the HTML file locally, the video plays with no errors. When I try to access the same HTML file from another HTML page, using a picture as a link, the first scene of the video is black with no audio. The second scene works fine and then when you dive into training sections, none of those play either.

Any suggestions on what could be affecting this HTML file that includes the video to run differently if called through a link.

code I am using:

```
<div style="width: 700px; margin:20px; float: left; border-right: 1px solid #ccc">

<p class="title" style="margin:20px"><b>DART 10.4</b></p>
<a target="_blank" href="\MSTR10\story_html5.html">
    <img src="\MSTR10\Logo.png" alt="DART 10.4" style="width:640px;height:360px;border:0;">
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

did you try putting in the fill exact path ?

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer

Comment: I have tried adding the full file path but the result is the same